# postcss-rtl doesn't affect the stylesheet in Angular

Tags: angular, webpack, sass, postcss

In an Angular application: I have a .scss file (with some imports), that I wish to render to .css, then pass through postcss-rtl. This needs to happen in both 'serve' mode and 'build' mode.

No matter what I try, the final .css file appears to *not* be modified by postcss-rtl. I have added my own webpack.config.js using @angular/builders, and it appears to load properly. I have tried everything I could think of, but no luck. This is my latest attempt, but I have tried many configurations/ Can anyone help?

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [ {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      use: [
        { loader: 'postcss-loader',
          options: {
            plugins: function () {
              return [ require( 'postcss-rtl' )({}) ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    } ]
  }
};
```

Comment: Have you found any solution? We're using the same angular builders and having the same issue.